# How to get byte size from objective-c type encoding

Tags: objective-c, reflection

Using NSMethodSignature I can get a methods argument types via getArgumentTypeAtIndex:. Which returns a c-string based off of [this documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100-SW1) So like "i" for int and "I" for unsigned.

Is there a function somewhere that takes in this encoding and returns the types size in bytes?

Something like this:

```
int paramSize = typeEncodingSize("i");
NSLog(@"%s is %d bytes", "i", paramSize);
//this would be the encoding for a struct that has three fields. An id, a pointer and an int.
paramSize = typeEncodingSize("{example=@*i}"); //two 8 byte pointers & one 4 byte int
NSLog(@"%s is %d bytes", "{example=@*i}", paramSize); 

which would output: 
i is 4 bytes
{example=@*i} is 20 bytes
```

I figure there must be an api function for this somewhere since the [docs for [NSInvocation setArgument:atIndex:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) say

> The number of bytes copied is determined by the argument size.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this is old, but I've hit the same wall.

The solution seems to be method `NSGetSizeAndAlignment`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSGetSizeAndAlignment

Comment: This works nicely, thanks! Looks like the doc has moved to: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395334-nsgetsizeandalignment

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `sizeof()`? That's the usual way to determine the size of a struct or other type.

Comment: unfortunately, sizeof doesn't help me. sizeof works when you know the type at compile time, but I'm trying to do it dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Caleb's `sizeof()` is correct, because basically you can pass anything to `@encode` only if it's also accepted by `sizeof()`.There's nothing like `@decode`. You can download [class-dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) source code and look into `CDTypeParser.m` file for example how to parse it.

Comment: sizeof wouldn't work for my use case. I need to determine this dynamically at runtime, but I'll take a look at class-dump.